# Training CNN: Understanding number data generated while training the model

Tags: machine-learning, machine-learning-model, computer-vision

I am training CNN on kaggle and my training and test datasets shapes are as follows:

```
(12271, 100, 100, 1) train shape
(3068, 1, 100, 100) test shape

(12271,) train target shape
(3068,) test target shape
```

But when I am training my network with below code, I am getting fllowing output while training, what does it mean. Does it mean  validation score is only calculated on `95` samples instead of `3068`? I am not sure what does this number 95 denotes at the start of each epoch?
Why is it happening?

````
for i in range(len(model)):
    model[i].fit_generator(datagen.flow(x_train,y_train, batch_size=batch_size),
                                        epochs = epochs, steps_per_epoch=x_train.shape[0] // batch_size,
                                        validation_data = (x_test,y_test), 
                                        callbacks=[ReduceLROnPlateau(monitor='loss', patience=3, factor=0.1)], 
                                        verbose=2)
    models.append(model[i])

Epoch 1/700
95/95 - 12s - loss: 3.4509 - accuracy: 0.3898 - val_loss: 2.8512 - val_accuracy: 0.4198
Epoch 2/700
95/95 - 11s - loss: 3.2385 - accuracy: 0.4420 - val_loss: 4.5017 - val_accuracy: 0.0975
Epoch 3/700
95/95 - 12s - loss: 2.7225 - accuracy: 0.4928 - val_loss: 4.3058 - val_accuracy: 0.4654
Epoch 4/700
95/95 - 11s - loss: 2.5231 - accuracy: 0.5203 - val_loss: 3.7107 - val_accuracy: 0.4501
Epoch 5/700
95/95 - 11s - loss: 2.2600 - accuracy: 0.5358 - val_loss: 1.9277 - val_accuracy: 0.5639
Epoch 6/700
95/95 - 12s - loss: 2.0255 - accuracy: 0.5529 - val_loss: 1.7618 - val_accuracy: 0.5896
Epoch 7/700
95/95 - 11s - loss: 1.8013 - accuracy: 0.5756 - val_loss: 1.4528 - val_accuracy: 0.6040
Epoch 8/700
95/95 - 11s - loss: 1.6182 - accuracy: 0.5942 - val_loss: 1.1788 - val_accuracy: 0.6858
```
````

Answer (score 0):

`95` is not number of samples, it equals to testset divided by batch_size: `testset // batch_size` in other words `steps` in per epoch